# use makefile to copy files in docker multi-stage builds

Tags: docker, make

I'm using multi-stage builds to separate the build environment from the final docker image:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic AS build
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    [...]
RUN wget https://someserver.com/somefile.tar.gz && \
    tar xvzf somefile.tar.gz && \
    ./configure && \
    make && make install && \
    [missing part]

FROM ubuntu:bionic
COPY --from=build /tmp/fakeroot/ /
[...]
```

Is there an easy way to collect all files that where created/copied while `make install` was running?

Currently I'm using a combination of `ldd` and individual file copy to get them all:

```
cp /etc/xyz/* /tmp/fakeroot/xyz
cp --parents $(ldd /usr/sbin/nginx | grep -o '/.\+\.so[^ ]*' | sort | uniq) /tmp/fakeroot
```

But as make install already has the information of which file to copy to what directory I'm asking myself if there isn't any way to use this mechanism.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way I found now is using [checkinstall](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man8/checkinstall.8.html) which replaces the `make install` step and tracks the installation to produce a package in the first stage. Then in the second stage I'm using `dpkg` to install this package.

So now I'm doing:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic AS build
RUN [...]
    ./configure && \
    make && \
    checkinstall --install=no --default && \
    cp XYZ-*.deb /XYZ.deb

FROM ubuntu:bionic
COPY --from=build /XYZ.deb /
RUN dpkg -i /XYZ.deb && \
    rm /XYZ.deb && \
    [...]
```

Any downsides of this approach?

Answer (score 1):

`./configure --prefix=/path/to/somewhere` will force `make install` to deploy all files under `/path/to/somewhere`

So it is easy to copy all files from this place in the second stage.

Comment: but won't this prefix possibly be also used for other paths while building? depending on the make file this could be compiled into the binary and then I'm fixed to that path in the next stage.

Comment: you can also use the same prefix for other builds. in the last stage, you still have `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables available to fix any issue while trying to execute binaries.

Comment: I've been following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307465/destdir-and-prefix-of-make and came to the conclusion that using `--prefix` and `DESTDIR` are not as reliable as I want.